# Can rewrite be used to mask a subpage of a main domain as a subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, url-rewriting, subdomain

We are running a WordPress website and, for ease of use for our vendors, we would like to have the login page show up at:

http://my.website.com/

The original url is http://website.com/login

Is this possible or will I have to create a new page to host on http://my.website.com and work out a way to login to http://website.com from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using mod_rewrite. Put these rules (above any wordpress rules that you already have) in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.website.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /login [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! Trying to get it working still.. can you provide a bit of an explanation of what each line is doing so I can understand a little better?

Comment: Issue was that I needed to use Zeus rewrite rules. Now on apache rewrites and this worked.